# Lost .h file association in XCode due to empty IBClassDescriber element in .xib

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xib

NOTE: Perhaps this question could be answered by a pure Objective-C expert as well? I work primarily in MonoTouch, but I think this problem may *not* be MonoTouch-specific.

Typically when the Assistant Editor in XCode won't show my `.h` file, I just [close everything, delete my obj directory, and rebuild all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475120/xcode-has-lost-associating-from-xib-to-h-file-monotouch). I wait for the `Indexing` process to complete. But this time I really can't get the `.h` file to show up, and thus I'm unable to add any new outlets to my `FooViewController`.

So far, I've tracked it down to an empty `IBClassDescriber` element in my `FooViewController.xib`

```
<object class="IBClassDescriber" key="IBDocument.Classes"/>
```

which should look something more like:

```
<object class="IBClassDescriber" key="IBDocument.Classes">
        <array class="NSMutableArray" key="referencedPartialClassDescriptions">
                <object class="IBPartialClassDescription">
                        <string key="className">FooViewController</string>
                        <string key="superclassName">UIViewController</string>
                        <dictionary class="NSMutableDictionary" key="outlets">
                            ...
                        </dictionary>
                        <dictionary class="NSMutableDictionary" key="toOneOutletInfosByName">
                            ...
                        </dictionary>
                        <object class="IBClassDescriptionSource" key="sourceIdentifier">
                                <string key="majorKey">IBProjectSource</string>
                                <string key="minorKey">./Classes/FooViewController.h</string>
                        </object>
                </object>
        </array>
</object>
```

which has the link to the `.h` file in the `minorKey` of `IBClassDescriptionSource`.

I've tried cleaning my project, closing all my apps and deleting the `obj` and `bin` directories. I've tried renaming the file (along with the above). And other various sporadic cursing and deleting/reverting/and banging things loudly. To no avail.

Anyone know how to recover the `IBClassDescriber` element once it's been emptied?

I'm going to have a look back through the file history and see when it disappeared. Maybe that'll give me a clue.

Thanks!
CM

Comment: Halfway there... I'm able to recreate the scenario where `IBClassDescriptionSource` gets set to empty. Details to come when I figure this out. But, quickly, if you create FooViewController, then change the `Register("FooViewController")` in the `.designer` file (perhaps from renaming), when you _save_ the file in XCode, the `IBClassDescriber` entry will be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this scenario came about (like other people have done) when I had renamed my `ViewController` file and failed to update all references to the old name. There are several places the name of the view controller needs to change, but there are really only 2 critical places that need to match to get XCode and MonoDevelop in synch. For this example, assume I had a view controller named `FooViewController` and had renamed it to `BarViewController`.

First, every time you launch XCode (XC), MonoDevelop (MD) creates a temporary directory named `obj/XCode/#` where `#` starts at 0 and increments by one every time you re-launch XC. The number resets to 0 every time you restart MD. Every time you close XC and return to MD, the directory will be deleted.

NOTE: the directory will NOT be deleted if you are browsing the directory from Finder or Terminal, etc.

MD creates the required `.h` and `.m` files in that directory that XC expects to see. The names of these files are based on the value if the `Register` attribute in `YourViewController.designer.cs`. In my case, I had properly updated the `.designer` file to:

```
[Register ("BarViewController")]
```

Now when I open the `.xib` I get the dreaded `No Assistant Results` error.

At this point, my `.xib` file, when opened in the Source Code Editor of MD, showed a full `IBClassDescriber` section (though improperly referencing `./Classes/FooViewController.h` since I hadn't updated it yet).

What I did next was to **save** the `.xib` from XC. Since XC could not find `./Classes/FooViewController.h` (MD was now generating `BarViewController.h`), it deleted the `IBClassDescriber` section from the `.xib`, giving me an empty entity

```
<object class="IBClassDescriber" key="IBDocument.Classes"/>
```

I had failed to update the `.xib` properly, now I had lost this entire section (which had numerous references that I didn't want or know how to recreate).

The key to fixing this was noticing that the `-1.CustomClassname` property in the `.xib` was set incorrectly. Updating it to match the `Register` setting

```
<dictionary class="NSMutableDictionary" key="flattenedProperties">
    <string key="-1.CustomClassName">BarViewController</string>
    ...
</dictionary>
```

and re-saving the file resulted in XC recreating the entire `IBClassDescriber` section with proper references to the `.h` file

```
<object class="IBClassDescriber" key="IBDocument.Classes">
        <array class="NSMutableArray" key="referencedPartialClassDescriptions">
                <object class="IBPartialClassDescription">
                        <string key="className">BarViewController</string>
                        <string key="superclassName">UIViewController</string>
                        <object class="NSMutableDictionary" key="outlets">
                            ...
                        </object>
                        <object class="NSMutableDictionary" key="toOneOutletInfosByName">
                            ...
                        </object>
                        <object class="IBClassDescriptionSource" key="sourceIdentifier">
                                <string key="majorKey">IBProjectSource</string>
                                <string key="minorKey">./Classes/BarViewController.h</string>
                        </object>
                </object>
        </array>
</object>
```

So in summary, when you're renaming files, the places to change are:

1. Refactor/Rename your main ViewController class (e.g. `FooViewController.cs` to `BarViewControllercs`. Using Refactor (right click class file -> refactor -> rename) will update lots of stuff for you, including the `.designer` file and any references to the class throughout your code
2. Change the string value passed to the superclass in your ViewController constructor `public GrepViewController () : base ("BarViewController", null)` which is required for loading the class at runtime
3. Open your `.designer` file and change the `Register` call so that the link between XC and MD is maintained: `[Register ("BarViewController")] partial class BarViewController`
4. Rename the `.xib`: `BarViewController.xib`
5. Open `BarViewController.xib` in MD with source editor (right click -> open with -> Source Code Editor) and change the `-1.CustomClassName` key: `<string key="-1.CustomClassName">BarViewController</string>`
6. Save the `.xib` from MD
7. Open `BarViewController.xib` in XC. (If you've got it open in MD, you'll need to right click -> Open With -> XCode). Wait for indexing to complete, then open the Assistant Editor. Notice that `BarViewController.h` is (correctly) opened.
8. Save the `.xib` from XC.
9. Open the `.xib` in MD and notice that `IBClassDescriber` section is fully specified, even if it was empty to start with.

Ship it!

Hope this helps someone, clears up some mystery of the linkage between XC and MD, or at least reminds me what to do next time I run into this problem.

Cheers,
CM

Comment: Note: I will accept this as the answer when SO allows me (in 2 days).